# Load URL into CSS-animated sliding iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iframe, css-animations

**I'd like to open a link in an css animated extending iframe.**

**My Problem: the href/url is not loading when i click on the link. I can just trigger the iframe's css animation. (maybe the js overwrites the href?)**

At some point I separated the requests into two links for tests: one loading the extending iframe and another one for loading the page into the now visible iframe, which worked. But as soon as i put both links together, the url wont load.

I tried alot of other things and searched alot of jQuery-Plugins but didn't find a fitting solution yet.
Thanks in advance for any help!

here's the fiddle for the live demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/10jew169/2/

here's the css for the sliding iframe :

```
 /*iframe styling*/
    #slideiniframe {
        height: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        border: none;
        margin: 0;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        background: url(img/preloader.gif) #d8d8d8 center no-repeat;
        max-width: 800px;
    }
    /*iframe animation*/
    .hide {
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 0%;
        padding-top: 0;
        padding-bottom: 0;
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
        -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
        -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
        transition-duration: 0.3s;
        -moz-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0.5, 1);
        -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0.5, 1);
        -o-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0.5, 1);
        transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0.5, 1);
    }
    .show {
        transition-duration: 0.3s;
        -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
        -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
        -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
        transition-timing-function: ease-in;
        -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
        -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
        -o-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
        width: 50%;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
```

And the body's html with the js/jquery for activating the css animation:

```
<!--article preview with two links to the iframe-->
<div class="post-content">
  <h2>The World's Coolest Passport Stamps</h2>
  <div class="body-text">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</p>
    <p><a class="read_more" href="http://travel-and-leisure-yahoopartner.tumblr.com/post/142022520144/the-worlds-coolest-passport-stamps" target="articleiframe">Keep reading</a></p>


<!--full article in iframe-->
<iframe id="slideiniframe" class="hide" name="articleiframe">
<p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>

<!--slide in animated when clicked on link and hide when clicked elsewhere--> 
<script>
$('.read_more').click(function(){
    $('#slideiniframe').toggleClass('show').toggleClass('hide');
    return false;
});

$(window).ready(function(){
    $('html').click(function(){
    $('#slideiniframe').addClass('hide').removeClass('show');
     });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the `href` value to the `src` attribute of the iFrame.

```
$('.read_more').click(function() {
    $('#slideiniframe').prop('src', $(this).prop('href'))
    $('#slideiniframe').toggleClass('show').toggleClass('hide');
    return false;
});
```